# How to get Max Date Value of Date column in Multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example I have 2 tables in Database.
Ex : 
Table T :

```
declare @t table (name varchar(20),DOB date)
Insert into @t (name,DOB) values ('Mohan','2001-07-19')
Insert into @t (name,DOB) values ('Minu','1998-06-19')
```

Table : TT

```
declare @tt table (name varchar(20),DOB date)
Insert into @tt (name,DOB) values ('Raju','2010-07-19')
Insert into @tt (name,DOB) values ('Rani','2001-06-19')
```

Now I have a Query to get Table name and column names of multiple tables basing on Date type filter .

```
SELECT   C.TABLE_SCHEMA, c.TABLE_NAME,c.COLUMN_NAME
FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
         JOIN sys.objects o ON o.name = c.TABLE_NAME   
WHERE    o.type = 'U' AND C.DATA_TYPE = 'Datetime'
```

Output :

```
T_Schema    T_name T_column
  dbo         T      DOB   
  dbo         TT     DOB
```

But how can I get max Date of both tables like below output :

```
  T_Schema  T_name T_column  Max_dt
  dbo         T      DOB     2001-07-19
  dbo         TT     DOB     2010-07-19
```

Suggest me the best way to achieve this.

Comment: @RyanWilson The problem is how to do it dynamically, i.e. query all tables

Comment: How about some dynamic SQL?

Comment: So you want a row returned for every datetime column in your database that gives you the schema, table name, column name and max date? Basically the query you have will get 99%, you just need to make it dynamic sql and you are there.

Comment: You can dinamically build a query string and execute it. I'd better create a stored procedure for this. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Comment: @ZorgoZ why is a stored procedure a better way to do this?

Comment: yes I agree I will filter some of the tables in WHERE condition but how I need to proceed with Dynamic or other solutions..

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this without a cursor, it's a bit nasty to say the least.

Comment: @mohan111, you will end up using a cursor, building a quite complex string. If you don't want to issue always from your code as t-sql script, SPs provide a clear layer for such tasks.

Comment: This can be done without a cursor. I will post an alternate in a few minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL to BUILD SQL for you

```
DECLARE @SQL as nvarchar(max) ='';
select @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT ' + Column_Name + ' adate, ''' + Column_Name + ''' colname, ''' + Table_name + ''' tabname  FROM ' +  Table_name + ' UNION ' FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where data_type like '%date%'
select @SQL = 'SELECT TOP 100 * FROM (' + LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) -6) + ') IQ  WHERE IQ.adate IS NOT null ORDER BY IQ.adate DESC';

 --cut n paste the sql below, see what it does for you
select @SQL
```

mark II - executes sql for you, and sorts out names with spaces in them

```
DECLARE @SQL as nvarchar(max) ='';
select @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT [' + Column_Name + '] adate, ''' + Column_Name + ''' colname, ''' + Table_name + ''' tabname  FROM [' +  Table_name + '] UNION ' FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where data_type like '%date%'
select @SQL = 'SELECT TOP 100 * FROM (' + LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) -6) + ') IQ  WHERE IQ.adate IS NOT null ORDER BY IQ.adate DESC';

select @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is another option that doesn't use a cursor. I doubt it will be any better from a performance perspective because you still need a subquery for every row. But I really hate cursors. I also used the system tables instead of the information schema views as those can sometimes be a bit odd. https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = N''

select @SQL = @SQL + 
    N'select SCHEMA_NAME = ''' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + ''', TABLE_NAME = ''' 
        + QUOTENAME(o.name) + ''', COLUMN_NAME = '''
        + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ''', MaxDate = '
        + '(select MAX(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ') from  ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name) + ') UNION ALL '
from sys.columns c
join sys.systypes st on st.type = c.system_type_id
join sys.objects o on o.object_id = c.object_id and o.type = 'U'
join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = o.schema_id
where st.name = 'datetime'
order by s.name
    , o.name
    , c.name

set @SQL = left(@SQL, len(@SQL) - 10) --removes final UNION ALL

select @SQL

--uncomment below when you are satisfied the dynamic sql is correct
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Ugh....lemme fix the casing. I am usually better than that. Especially since I use a case sensitive environment for our biggest system. Although the builtin function names are not case sensitive even in a case sensitive collation.

Comment: Latin1_BIN from memory? I used to really like using that as a base collation, really keeps you on your toes.

Comment: @DavidG that is the collation our ERP uses. Still doesn't care about case sensitivity of built in function names. But it really does keep things interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some dynamic SQL that should do what you want, via a cursor.

I'd caution using this if you have a lot of tables, or run this in test first. Cursors are not great performs generally speaking. You can run this against a system database, like master, which would have fewer values to see how it works.

```
create table #MaxDate (tname varchar(256), cname varchar(256), mdate datetime)

declare cur cursor local fast_forward
for 
    SELECT   C.TABLE_SCHEMA, c.TABLE_NAME,c.COLUMN_NAME
    FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
             JOIN sys.objects o ON o.name = c.TABLE_NAME   
    WHERE    o.type = 'U' AND C.DATA_TYPE = 'Datetime'

declare @schema varchar(64), @table varchar(256), @column varchar(256)
declare @sql varchar(max)

open cur
fetch next from cur into @schema, @table, @column 
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

begin
    set @sql = 'select ''' + @table + '''' + ',''' + '' + @column + '''' + ',' +  'max(' + @column + ') from ' + @schema + '.' + @table
    print @sql

    insert into #MaxDate
    exec (@sql)
    fetch next from cur into @schema, @table, @column
end

close cur
deallocate cur

select * from #MaxDate
drop table #MaxDate
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer using a cursor, dynamic SQL and a temporary table:

```
DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT
    C.TABLE_SCHEMA,
    c.TABLE_NAME,
    c.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
JOIN sys.objects o
    ON o.name = c.TABLE_NAME
WHERE o.type = 'U'
AND C.DATA_TYPE = 'Datetime'

DECLARE @schema SYSNAME
DECLARE @table SYSNAME
DECLARE @column SYSNAME
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)

CREATE TABLE #Data (SchemaName SYSNAME, TableName SYSNAME, ColumnName SYSNAME, MaxDate DATETIME)

OPEN table_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @schema, @table, @column

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO #Data (SchemaName, TableName, ColumnName, MaxDate) SELECT '''+@schema+''', '''+@table+''', '''+@column+''', MAX(['+@column+']) FROM ['+@schema+'].['+@table+']'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @schema, @table, @column
END

CLOSE table_cursor
DEALLOCATE table_cursor

SELECT * FROM #Data
DROP TABLE #Data
```

Comment: better version here since you use sysname on your variables :D

Comment: apart from cursor any other way

Comment: @scsimon Dunno where I dragged sysname from, some repressed memory from many moons ago!

Comment: @mohan111 Sean Lange said he was going to post a way without a cursor... it's probably going to have a while loop or a recursive CTE.

Comment: @scsimon I would never suggest a while loop over a well defined cursor. And a rCTE here would be essentially a hidden loop because it would be like using one for counting.

Comment: @mohan111 What's the difference? While loop, cursor, dynamically constructed union - they're all the same, you have to lump together results from reading multiple tables.

Comment: @AaronBertrand yep...that is why in my answer I said it wasn't going to perform any better. No matter how you slice it this kind of thing has to query all those tables anyway.

Comment: @SeanLange more of me spitballing if how you could. I didn’t foresee the union method. 

Comment: thanks for very great discussion I will implement the code in my requirement @DavidG