# Find out the MAX value of a column that is present in multiple table and in multiple schema using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find the max value of a column which is present in multiple tables. Eg.

```
SELECT MAX(UpdatedDatetime) FROM schema_1.table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(UpdatedDatetime) FROM schema_1.table_2
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(UpdatedDatetime) FROM schema_2.table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(UpdatedDatetime) FROM schema_2.table_2
```

Clearly the above method is quite cumbersome when there are say more than 100 tables.
Is there any way to dynamically generate the table name as above and form the query string?

I mean using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this with dynamic SQL using the information schema tables. What have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Max Date Value of Date column in Multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51598128/how-to-get-max-date-value-of-date-column-in-multiple-tables)

Comment: `Why this was downvoted?` Only the person who downvoted can tell that, and he/she is not obligated to do so, unfortunatly. My guess is that in your question there is no visible effort from your part on what you have tried already, and what you have researched

Comment: And why would rows of a single column containing a datetime be useful? This seems to be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) perhaps based on a database design problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below should do the work. You can always use `String_AGG` function. But in my sql server this function is not supported so using `XML path`.

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max)

SELECT @SQL=STUFF((SELECT  '  ' + CAST(Name AS VARCHAR(max)) [text()]
       FROM (
       SELECT 'select Max(UpdatedDatetime) from ' + QUOTENAME(ss.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(st.name) + ' union all' as Name
       FROM sys.tables st
       INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss on st.[schema_id] = ss.[schema_id]
       WHERE st.is_ms_shipped = 0
       AND EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM sys.columns sc
          WHERE sc.[object_id] = st.[object_id]
          AND sc.name = 'UpdatedDatetime'
         )
       ) ap
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
      .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') 

      set @SQL = left(@SQL, len(@SQL) - 10) -- remove last union all

      select @SQL
      EXEC (@SQL)
```